# How do I fix the Power Automate Syntax Error

Tags: odata, power-automate

I am attempting to create a Power Automate Approval Workflow for Sales orders that push the customer over their credit limit. When I try to pull in the customer credit limit I am getting a Syntax Error: Syntax error at position 5 in 'Sell-to Customer No. eq 'EEGA''. using the following string: Sell-to Customer No. eq '@{outputs('Get_Sales_Order')?['body/sellToCustomerNumber']}'

Odata Config

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the V2 API category with the customers table? When you know the customer number you should be able to retrieve the credit limit.

```
number eq '10000'
```

Alternatively, you could also filter on other properties like DisplayName, etc.

[image]

Comment: No dice, I get an error: ErrorCode: BadRequest  Could not find a property named sellToCustomerNumber. I did check and the field name is actually Sell-to Customer No.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your current flow setup? This might help the troubleshooting.

Comment: I uploaded the image to my post. I found the Customer Number is stored in a couple of Fields on the customer card so I changed my query to pull from a field that had no space. The field name is called No. and I am still getting the same syntax error despite matching what Microsoft has for documentation on setting up an Odata Filter.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that screenshot. I see you are using Business Central. Let me have a look in my Business Central demo environment and see if I can reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we have solved this one. In looking at the return error info, the Field Name was called No. but the actual field was called number. We updated this parameter and now the workflow for Sales Orders that exceed the customers credit limit is going out for an approval as expected. Thank you for looking at this.